# What is the answer to this question?

Tags: volume

A cylinder with closed ends has a total surface area ; the radius of the base is  and the height is . Find an expression for  in terms of  and .

The expression I get cancels down to $√a^2=a$ which seems obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** The total surface area $S$ of a closed cylinder with radius $a$ & height $ka$ is given as
$$S=2\pi (a)(ka)+2\pi a^2$$

Comment: I've been through this step, but I want to keep the S as it is, not introduce more a's.

Comment: Well, after simplifying, you will get $$2\pi a^2( k+1)=S\implies a=\sqrt{\frac{S}{2\pi(k+1)}}$$

Comment: where do you get the $k+1$

Comment: ah nevermind I never thought of factorising.

Comment: $k$ comes from height $ka$ and $k+1$ comes when you take $a^2$ common out of $2\pi ka^2+2\pi a^2$